# Oraoop disabled for Sqoop import

Tags: sqoop, hortonworks-data-platform

I'm using the Hortonworks HDP Sandbox, and I’ve installed Oraoop per the instructions, but whenever I run a Sqoop import I get the message “oracle.OraOopManagerFactory: Data Connector for Oracle and Hadoop is disabled.”. I’m not sure what else I need to do for it to pick it up. I have verified that the oraoop driver is in my sqoop lib directory. The imports do work, but they are just using the oracle driver, and I would like to play around with some of the features that you get with Oraoop.

This is the command I'm running:

```
sqoop-import --connect jdbc:oracle:thin:@<ip>:1521/sid --username myUser -P --query "select * from mytable where \$CONDITIONS" -split-by sequence_id -as-sequencefile --target-dir /user/hue/data/deactivatedsponsor
```

Answer (score 1):

If '--query' argument is specified in place of '--table' parm, Oraoop connector is not used.
Following is mentioned in [Sqoop Documentation](http://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.6/SqoopUserGuide.html#_data_connector_for_oracle_and_hadoop_exports)

> Data Connector for Oracle and Hadoop accepts responsibility for those Sqoop Jobs with the following attributes:
>
> Oracle-related
>
> Table-Based - Jobs where the table argument is used and the specified object is a table.

Following command should use Oraoop Connector. I have included "--direct" option as well which indicates to Sqoop that Oraoop should be used.

```
sqoop-import --connect jdbc:oracle:thin:@<ip>:1521/sid --direct --username myUser -P --table mytable -split-by sequence_id -as-sequencefile --target-dir /user/hue/data/deactivatedsponsor --columns <columns list> --where <where condition if needed>
```

Answer (score 0):

Oraoop connector cannot process `--query` tool, when you use `--query` it automatically invokes `sqoop`.
So instead of using `--query` use `--table` for import.
Hope this helps!!