# how to enable oraoop for sqoop 1.4.6

Tags: hadoop, oracle11g, sqoop

I am using `sqoop` 1.4.6 and `Oracle 11g` with `ojdbc6` driver.

I wanted to know since `oraoop` is built in `sqoop` 1.4.6 then why do I get this info in the log while running a `sqoop` job.

`INFO oracle.OraOopManagerFactory: Data Connector for Oracle and Hadoop is disabled.`

My job successfully runs but I know that `oraoop` connector is faster than just `JDBC`. How do I enable `oraoop`?

Thanks

Comment: You should search for '--direct' mode in Sqoop user guide https://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.6/SqoopUserGuide.html

Answer (score 3):

[If '--query' argument is specified in place of '--table' parm, Oraoop connector is not used.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31998866/2079249)

Also check if `oraoop` is configured for correctly:

- [download](http://www.cloudera.com/downloads/connectors/sqoop/oracle/1-6.html)/check - `oraoop-version.jar` file available at `$SQOOP_HOME/lib`
- create/check - `oraoop-site-template.xml` file available at `$SQOOP_HOME/conf`
- check/add - `oraoop` file at available at `$SQOOP_HOME/conf/managers.d`

Detailed configurations steps are explained:

- [configure_the_data_connector_for_oracle_and_hadoop](https://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.6/SqoopUserGuide.html#_configure_the_data_connector_for_oracle_and_hadoop)
- [oraoop user guide](http://blog.cloudera.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/01/oraoopuserguide-With-OraHive.pdf) and [oraoopuserguide_1.6](http://www.cloudera.com/documentation/other/connectors.html/PDF/oraoopuserguide_1.6.pdf)
- [confirm_the_data_connector_for_oracle_and_hadoop_can_initialize_the_oracle_session](https://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.6/SqoopUserGuide.html#_confirm_the_data_connector_for_oracle_and_hadoop_can_initialize_the_oracle_session)

Answer (score 1):

`Oraoop` connector is an internal utility of `sqoop` from `version 1.4.6`, so for `oraoop` to be invoked your `sqoop command` must be oraoop specific.
For starters your sqoop command cannot contain `--query` tool as oraoop doesn't supports that, apart from that `oraoop` is only invoked for more than one mappers.

If you are doing all these things right then you can try two more things:

1. Using the `--direct` option
2. Use this with your oraoop query `-D oraoop.disabled=false`

A sample working oraoop query is :

```
sqoop import --connect jdbc:oracle:thin:@127.0.0.1:1521:XE --username ROOT --password manager --table temp --target-dir /sqoop/tmp1 -m 3
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the `--direct` parameter if I remember correctly.